# Upgrading MySQL Connector/ODBC massively degrades performance

Tags: mysql, docker, odbc, pyodbc, mysql-connector

When upgrading from `mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19` to `mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.29` I am noticing a ~70% reduction in speed of execution.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.29-debian
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  test:
    build: ./
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

ARG odbcdlurl
RUN { apt-get update && apt install -y unixodbc-dev && wget -qO- $odbcdlurl | tar -xvz -C / --strip-components 1; } && \
    cp /lib/libmyodbc8* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/ && \
    /bin/myodbc-installer -d -a -n "MySQL" -t "DRIVER=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so;"
RUN pip3 install pyodbc==4.0.32
RUN printf '\n\
import timeit \n\
import pyodbc \n\
mysql_conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so;SERVER=db;DATABASE=sys;UID=root;PWD=example;charset=utf8mb4;") \n\
mysql_cursor = mysql_conn.cursor() \n\
mysql_cursor.execute("SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;") \n\
mysql_cursor.execute("SET global log_output = \x27table\x27;") \n\
mysql_cursor.execute("create temporary table temp(junkvarchar varchar(100));") \n\
start_time = timeit.default_timer() \n\
mysql_cursor.executemany("insert into temp(junkvarchar) values (?)", [("a"*100,) for i in range(100000)]) \n\
print(f"Elapsed Time: {timeit.default_timer() - start_time}") \n\
' >> /test.py
CMD sleep 20 && python3 '/test.py'
```

**Results:**

```
ODBC 8.0.19:
docker-compose down && docker-compose build --build-arg odbcdlurl=https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit.tar.gz && docker-compose up
result: ~13 seconds

ODBC 8.0.29:
docker-compose down && docker-compose build --build-arg odbcdlurl=https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.29-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit.tar.gz && docker-compose up
result: ~21 seconds
```

**Test Environments:**

I have tested on Docker Desktop 4.8.2 (79419) Windows 10 Pro (19044.1706), as well as AWS EKS, and another Linux Dev machine I have. Point being the results seem consistent regardless of Docker version, OS, or orchestration framework.

**The Question:**

Why is this occurring and how can I update my ODBC Connector while also not destroying performance?

Comment: Let's see the generated query.  I would expect "executemany" to generate a single `INSERT` with lots of rows.  But did it?

Comment: "I would expect 'executemany' to generate a single INSERT with lots of rows." - Just going from memory here, but I don't think so. IIRC, MySQL Connector/Python does that, but (pyodbc with) MySQL Connector/ODBC doesn't.

Comment: @RickJames They are the same `insert into temp(junkvarchar) values ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')`
However interestingly, for every 100,000 inserts there is a corresponding `Reset stmt` When looking at the `mysql.general_log` for `8.0.29`. This did not occur in `8.0.19`. I think we are on to something...

Comment: Perhaps some timeout was exceeded?

Comment: I have also tested a bunch more versions of the ODBC Connector and have found that `8.0.26` was the last performant ODBC version provided. `8.0.27` and above (including the latest) all have the same performance issues.

Comment: It seems to be a bug report rather a stackoverflow.com question doesn't it? Probably it's better to report the issue to the developer?